# I know these are sixteenth sextuplets, but I was wondering what these are called when they share the same staff? And how they're played?

Tags: strings, string-instruments, cello, orchestral-strings

[image]

I am trying to figure out what they are, I've searched on YouTube but I don't think I have the correct keywords to find out what I'm looking for... Are they played like double stops or played differently?

Comment: What piece and composer?

Comment: One phrase that describes these is "needlessly complicated."

Comment: @phoog My money is on the MuseScore website.

Comment: @Aaron really?  The typography looks a bit more refined than what I'd expect from MuseScore.

Comment: @phoog The red highlight is a dead giveaway for the website, and it matches the alignment in MS3.

Answer (score 6):

You're right that the vertically aligned notes are meant to be played at the same time, but if this is an ensemble piece, the part is almost certainly intended to be played *divisi* (divided), where half the section plays the upper voice and the other half plays the lower.

The giveaways include how difficult it would be to play *non divisi* (in this case, extreme enough to override pretty much every other consideration, including composer intent) and the fact that they're notated as separate voices even though the rhythm is the same. The composer will usually write *divisi* when it applies and can also write *non divisi* to reinforce the default.

Answer (score 2):

As I suppose is clear by now the question isn't so much about the sixteenth sextuplets but about the two voices happening simultaneously.  As you say, you know that they are sixteenth sextuplets.

In support of the [answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/132276/2257) from [the-baby-is-you](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/52631/the-baby-is-you), double stops would normally be written with a single stem having two noteheads (at least for the last couple of centuries).  As a consequence of each double stop having a single stem, there would be one beam instead of two.  So even without knowing how difficult these would be to play as double stops, we can see that they aren't double stops.

Normally, downward-pointing stems belong to the lower voice and upward to the upper voice, so the fact that the parts "cross" here is confusing.  It requires the noteheads to be offset slightly.  I would first ask whether the parts should be swapped -- have the firsts play the higher notes -- to avoid this.  Perhaps it was done this way to allow the beams to be closer to the staff.

Another possibility is that this does not represent a divided cello section but rather divided cellos and basses.  In this case, all the cellos play the upward-pointing stems and all the basses the downward-pointing stems.  There should be a notation indicating this at the beginning of the division, but if the two sections are on the same staff and there is no such notation then you should probably assume that this is what it means.

Regardless, the score would be clearer if the two parts were put on two staves.